# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' - webpack issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I have the following error when trying to use a React grid component (from [Glide-Data-Grid](https://github.com/glideapps/glide-data-grid)) in my NextJS project. The error tells me there is an unexpected token '.' in a file inside the `nodes_modules` folder.

Yet, I tried to use this component in a new React project, in order to see if I have the same error, and everything works well.

How can I fix it in my NextJS project?

Error message:
[image]

`Image-overlay-editor.js` line 16:
[image]

My `next.config.js`:

```js
const { withExpo } = require('@expo/next-adapter');
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
const withFonts = require('next-fonts');
const withImages = require('next-images');
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins')

const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')([
  'expo-next-react-navigation',
  // you can add other modules that need traspiling here
])

module.exports = withPlugins(
  [withTM, withFonts, withCSS, withImages, [withExpo, { projectRoot: __dirname }]],
  {
    webpack: (config, options) => {

      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
        loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
        options: {
          presets: [
            ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
            [
              require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/dependencies'),
              { helpers: true }
            ]
          ],
          plugins: [
            ['@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types'],
            ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
          ],
        }
      });
       return config;
      }
    }
)
```